# How to clean browser cache from the client machine with new code deploy to the production server for angular app

Tags: angular, browser-cache

It is annoying every time when I deploy new code to tell the client to clean his cache in order to have the new changes. This is angular app. I see that when we build the code the .js file names are changed, but index.html is the same and may be this is the reason the app cache on the client machine to stay the same. How to have it updated? May be the question is not angular specific.

Comment: Most browsers support "hard" refreshes. On mozilla this is ctrl + f5 and on chrome I think you have to open the developer console and then press ctrl + f5(not sure about the chrome one). Caching is inherently an issue with deploying new code as browsers love to cache to improve loading times.

Comment: I assume the OP is looking for a solution more elegant than "tell the user to refresh cache".

Comment: When you build for prod using the angular-cli, the client-side files are generated with a new MD5, it should be refreshed without any action by the user.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by including the following lines in your index.html under 'head' (tag) section.

```html
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />  
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />  
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: I need to read more about the side effect of this. What basically this is doing is to fully remove caching for the app, but this would mean that every time the client loads the app in new tab, this would download all files from the app, which is slow. Am I correct